# Git reset hard error: ambiguous argument HEAD

Tags: git, reset

I need to reset my HEAD to where it was before the most recent pull.

I believe what I need to do is:
`git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`

But here is what git tells me.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD@1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: What OS are you on? It seems like the { and } are getting stripped.

Comment: What does `git log -- HEAD` show you?

Comment: Does it work if you use `'HEAD@{1}'`?

Comment: Fish was stripping the { and }

Answer (score 0):

Fish was stripping { and }

Bash works fine.

Comment: Think you better use quotes anyway (`like git reset --hard 'HEAD@{1}'`)